# Access static variable from static method

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, static-variables

I want to access a static variable from a static method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class Messenger:
    name = "world"
    @staticmethod
    def get_msg(grrrr):
        return "hello " + grrrr.name

print Messenger.get_msg(Messenger)
```

How to do it without passing `grrrr` to a method? Is this the true OOP?..

Anything like `name` or `self.name` seems not working:

```
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

and

```
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`. Found it just after writing the question.

In many languages (C++, Java etc.) "static" and "class" methods are synonyms. [Not in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

Answer (score 16):

```
def get_msg():
    return "hello " + Messenger.name
```

You can't use self.name because self is not defined. self is a naming convention for the first parameter of non-static or non-classmethod methods. It points to the object on which you called the method. Since your method is static, you don't need an object to call it on.

Comment: So to access a static variable within a static method of the class, I have to prefix the class name to the static variable I am accessing, like you have shown in your answer?

Comment: @RaynerDaCruz if you access it in a @staticmethod, then yes, you need to prefix the class name. If it's a @classmethod, then you can also use the `cls` argument of your method. Difference is well described here: https://medium.com/school-of-code/classmethod-vs-staticmethod-in-python-8fe63efb1797