# python class variable in static method

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, static-variables

[updated]: Full code

I always get confused with pyhton's staticmethods
but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233729/access-static-variable-from-static-method) (last answer), it should work!

getting error:

> AttributeError: class MyConnection has no attribute 'myuser'

```
class MyConnection:
    def __init__(self, hostname, port, user, password):
        myhostname = hostname
        myport = port
        myuser = user
        mypassword = password
        isisessid = None

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        my_session = MyConnection()

        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + string.strip(
            base64.encodestring(MyConnection.myuser + ':' + MyConnection.mypassword))

        body = json.dumps({'username': MyConnection.myuser, 'password': MyConnection.mypassword,
            'services': ['platform', 'namespace']})

        uri = '/session/1/session'

        connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(MyConnection.myhostname, MyConnection.myport)
        connection.connect()

        try:
            connection.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
            response = connection.getresponse()
            my_session.isisessid = MyConnection.extract_session_id(
                response.getheaders())
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            connection.close()
        except httplib.BadStatusLine, e:
            print e
            connection.close()

        return my_session
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with static methods. The error is in your `__init__`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18622179/429533

Comment: @Peter: [OT] make yourself a favour and use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/)

Comment: @spinus: Thanks for the suggestion, its not my code - trying to build a car without reinventing the wheels! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the attributes are going to be static, don't initialize them in the initializer method, declare them *outside* at the class level, not at method level.

But why are you initializing class attributes in the initializer? every instance that you create will overwrite their values!

I believe you're confusing what *instance* attributes and *class* attributes are used for. Why don't you try using only instance attributes? all things considered, having static data is *not* a good idea. For example:

```
class MyConnection:
    def __init__(self, hostname, port, user, password):
        self.myhostname = hostname
        self.myport = port
        self.myuser = user
        self.mypassword = password
    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        my_session = MyConnection()
        print my_session.myuser # just an example
```

Comment: Im creating an instance of class "my_session = MyConnection()" so I should use it to get its variables. duhh

Answer (score 2):

You have to define attributes in a class scope (static attributes) or in instance scope (in `__init__`).

So in class scope it looks like:

```
class Cls(object):
    class_scope_attribute = 1

    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        print Cls.class_scope_attribute

    @classmethod
    def metdho2(cls):
        print cls.class_scope_attribute

    def method3(self):
        print Cls.class_scope_attribute
        print self.__class__.class_scope_attribute
```

In instance scope:

```
class Cls2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_scope_attribute

    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        # cannot access the instance_scope_attribute
        pass

    @classmethod
    def method2(cls):
        # cannot access the instance_scope_attribute
        pass

    def method3(self):
        print self.instance_scope_attribute
```

Look at the `self` in `__init__` before variable name.

So, you have to add `self.` or move variables to class scope, but be careful as class scope attributes are shared by all instances.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is really to make `connect` a `@staticmethod`, then initialize `myhostname`,`myport`, `myuser`, and `mypassword` at the class level, like in:

```
    class MyConnection:
        myhostname= hostnameValue
        myport= portValue
        myuser= userValue
        mypassword= passwordValue

        @staticmethod
        def connect():
            my_session = MyConnection()

            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + string.strip( base64.encodestring( MyConnection.myuser + ':' + MyConnection.mypassword ) )

            body = json.dumps({'username': MyConnection.myuser, 'password': MyConnection.mypassword,'services': ['platform', 'namespace']})

            my_session.connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(MyConnection.myhostname, MyConnection.myport)
            my_session.connection.connect()

    MyConnection.connect()
```

Alternatively, you can leave them in `None` and give them a value before calling `connect()`.

If you want to make `connect` an instance method, then you are pretty much there.  You just need to remove decorator `@staticmethod`, and do a few other changes:

```
    class MyConnection:
        def __init__(self, hostname, port, user, password):
            self.myhostname = hostname
            self.myport = port
            self.myuser = user
            self.mypassword = password

        def connect():
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + string.strip( base64.encodestring(self.myuser + ':' + self.mypassword) )

            body = json.dumps({'username': self.myuser, 'password': self.mypassword, 'services': ['platform', 'namespace']})

            connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.myhostname, self.myport)
            connection.connect()

    my_session= MyConnection(hostnameValue,portValue,userValue,passwordValue)
    my_session.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

`classmethod` and `static method` cannot access varibles declared in  `__init__()` method.
Because `classmethod` and `staticmethod`  bound to the class and not the object of the class, hence they take class parameters that points to the class and not the object instance.

`__init__()` creates object instance, hence variables declared in `__init__()` cannot be accessed by `classmethod` and `staticmethod`, unless they are declared as class variables.

They can modify a class state that would apply across all the instances of the class. For example they can modify a class variable that will be applicable to all the instances.