# Access static method from static variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, static

There are plenty answers for how to access static variables from static methods (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233729/access-static-variable-from-static-method), and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707380/in-python-how-can-i-access-static-class-variables-within-class-methods), and the great info on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)), however I'm having trouble with the other direction: How can you use static methods to initialize static variables. E.g.:

```
import os, platform
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return 'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
    pth = os.path.join(A.getRoot(), 'some', 'path')
```

The last line gives an exception: `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`. The same error happens if I use `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`.

Is it possible to access a static method from a class variable?

Comment: Write the line outside of the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the class "A" doesn't exist yet at the moment your variable path is declared, so the evaluation fails. How about declaring it right after?

```
import os, platform
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return 'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
A.pth = os.path.join(A.getRoot(), 'some', 'path')
```

An uglier alternative would be:

```
import os, platform
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return 'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
    pth = os.path.join(getRoot.__func__(), 'some', 'path')
```

... but it's pretty unreadable (and depends on implementation details of @staticmethod, which is bad).

For this specific case I'd do something like this (which doesn't really answer your question, instead it sidesteps the need for it):

```
import os, platform
class A(object):
    _root = 'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return A._root
    pth = os.path.join(_root, 'some', 'path')
```

... because your platform is pretty unlikely to change while your program is still running, right? :) If you have a better reason to do something like that, maybe use one of the methods above.

Answer (score 1):

You can defer the evaluation of `pth` by using a `classproperty`:

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return 'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'
    @classproperty
    def pth(cls):
        return os.path.join(cls.getRoot(), 'some', 'path')
```

[`classproperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203659/2096752) is not a builtin, but it is a widely used recipe.

As a side note, IMHO, you should always prefer using `classmethod` over `staticmethod`.

Answer (score -1):

What I did in the end was have `A` extend a different class `B` which has the staticmethod I wanted. I.e.:

```
import os
import platform

class B(object):
    @staticmethod
    def getRoot():
        return r'C:\\' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else '/'

class A(B):
    pth = os.path.join(B.getRoot(), 'some', 'path')
```

Although this is what worked best for me it is more a work around rather than an answer.